# Goutte - TLSv1 protocol version error

Tags: php, curl, ssl, goutte, symfony-components

I'm using Goutte to get a page on a web server using an SSL certificate. Whenever I try to get this page the the following exception is thrown:

```
Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\\Http\\Exception\\CurlException' with message 
'[curl] 35: error:1407742E:SSL 
routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version 
[url] https://somesite.com
```

I have been looking online for this type of error. It seems that this error happens when there is a handshake failure. The server seems to support TLSv1 and the client uses SSL23.

**I'm not sure if this assessment is correct nor do I know how to correct it.**

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
<?php
use Goutte\Client;
$client = new Client();
$guzzle = $client->getClient();
$guzzle->setConfig( 
    array(
        'curl.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST' => false,
        'curl.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER' => false,
    )
);

$client->setClient($guzzle);
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://somesite.com'); // IT FAILS HERE
```

**UPDATE:**

NOTE: I started getting a few weeks ago a similar error, so I thought I would update the question and answer as they are related.

I got a similar error:

```
[curl] 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to website.com:443
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to this problem in the blogpost "[Fixing SSL Handshake with PHP5 and Curl](http://mikeytag.tumblr.com/post/29612114990/fixing-ssl-handshake-with-php5-and-curl)"

This error can happen in some operating systems but not in all making it a hard issue to replicate. I am currently using Ubuntu 12.04 in my development environment.

Thankfully this is something that can be addressed at the code level like this:

```
use Goutte\Client;
$client = new Client();
$guzzle = new GuzzleClient('https://somesite.com', array(
    'curl.options' => array(
        'CURLOPT_SSLVERSION' => 'CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1',
    )
));
$client->setClient($guzzle);
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://somesite.com');
```

**UPDATE:**

For the solution for the message

```
[curl] 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to website.com:443
```

was a bit tricky to resolve as the message gives no indication of what is going on.

[This](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/202#issuecomment-31698919) GitHub issue pointed me in the right direction tho. There are multiple versions of the CURLOPT_SSLVERSION I can use (of course!), but these include v1.0, v1.1, and v1.2! See the [curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for more information.

For this particular error I ended up using the following code:

```
$guzzle = new GuzzleClient('https://somesite.com', array(
    'curl.options' => array(
        'CURLOPT_SSLVERSION' => 'CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1',
    )
));
```

The site I was trying to connect to would not accept any other option including `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1`.